# Convert 24 hr format to 12 hr format

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be really easy but I can't figure it out. I am trying to convert the 24 hr time to a 12 hr time to display on the UI.

```
var hrs = '<%=Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour%>';
var hrs12 = hrs > 12 ? hrs - 12 : hrs;
$("#ScheduledHour").val(hrs12);
```

But the above is not working coz hrs is a string. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vFnh7/

Comment: simply use `var hrs = parseInt('your hours string here');`

Comment: This doesn't actually result in valid 12 hr format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `parseInt()`:

```
var hrs = '<%=Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour%>';
hrs = parseInt(hrs, 10) // converts the value to an integer
var hrs12 = hrs > 12 ? hrs - 12 : hrs;
$("#ScheduledHour").val(hrs12);
```

Comment: @dotNetNewbie what do you mean by _it shows $("#ScheduledHour").val(hrs12);_?

Comment: @Ramminson instead of the calculated value, it shows hrs12 inside the val function.

Comment: @dotNetNewbie it's not possible, what type of element is `#ScheduledHour`?

Comment: Oops... I am sorry. I had another line of code that was overwriting this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
var hrs = '<%=Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour%>'
    thrs = parseInt(hrs, 10);  // As hrs is string, so you need to convert it to
                               // integer using parseInt(str, radix), don't forget to use 
                               // radix parameter

var hrs12 = thrs > 12 ? thrs - 12 : thrs;
$("#ScheduledHour").val(hrs12);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `hrs` to a number:

```
hrs = '<%=Model.Scheduled.Value.Hour%>' * 1;
```

Also, your question is misleading. Really all you're asking is "How do I convert a string to a number in JavaScript?" In which case, Google probably could have helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your hrs variable to a number. There are a number of ways to do this, but parseInt is probably your best bet here...

parseInt: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to an int:

```
var hrsInt = parseInt(hrs);
```